# What does "$f(x)$ has a root of order $k$" mean?

Tags: roots

I'm confused by the wording of this, the question states:

> Assume $f(x)$ has a root of order $k=3$ at $x(n)$.

What does the "root of order $k=3$" part mean?

Thanks

Comment: It means the root occurs three times. For example, $x^3$ has a root of order 3 at x=0, since you could factor as $x^3=x*x*x$ and each factor would on its own cause the function to equal zero.

Answer (score 1):

You should say it has a root of order $3$ at some point, say $n$, not $x$ which is the variable you use for the function to avoid confusion.  Very roughly speaking, it means $f(x)$ looks like $(x-n)^3g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is finite and nonzero at $n$.  You have $f(n)=0, f'(n)=0, f''(n)=0, f'''(0) \neq 0$.  In some cases we mean it has a root of at least $3$ and you might have $f'''(n)=0$.  You need to figure that out from context.